# Intellisense VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know where can I find the intellisense file of VSCODE which I can edit and experiment with it, I've gone through almost all folders but couldn’t find the file.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you need to Customizing IntelliSense or you just need a file related to IntelliSense ?

Comment: I reckon if I get the file, I can customise it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your IntelliSense experience in settings and key bindings. Check these link for more details.
 https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/intellisense/#customizing-intellisense 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense